# Hello Experts - Updating multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 3 columns of data: 1. User 2. User Id 3. Role.

What I want to do is replace the User name with a value User_1, User_2, User_3..., then remove the User_id and retain the Role column. A user can have many roles, there are approximately 60k users. What I want is code to auto change the actual name of the user to User_1, User_2, User_3 etc. based on the number of roles that user has - any thoughts appreciated on how to acheive this in Excel.

So that:

```
Mr England Approver
Mr Wales Approver
Mr Wales Query Builder
Mr Wales Reports
Mrs Scotland Approver
Mrs Scotland Query Builder
Mr Ireland Approver
Mr France Query Builder
...and so on for all users - this to my mind is a 1 to many scenario
```

Comment: `What I want is code to auto change the actual name of the user to User_1, User_2, User_3 etc. based on the number of roles that user has`. To clarify: so a user with 1 role would be named `User_1` and a user with 3 roles would be named `User_3`?

Comment: By the way, in your question you mention 3 columns, but the example shows 2. Please edit your question to include example data for the right number of columns.

Comment: Hi Saaru - not quite the number of roles is just a number x - in my example above Mr England would become User 1...Mr Wales would become User 2...Mrs Scotland would become User 3 and so on. Mr France could have 20 roles but each one would have a corresponding value of User 4. Basically England, Wales, Scotland & France are 'real' names and cannot be exported out of a secure environment - so I need to replace with 'dummy' names User 1, User 2, User 3 and so on. But retain the count of roles each user has. Hope this now makes sense and thanks for your assistance Regards Simon

Comment: Agreed in terms of 3 columns I have a user in column 1, a user id in column 2 and I have the roles in column 3. I cannot show the real user name in column 1 nor can I show the user id in column 2.

Comment: We're not your personal programmers, but we're eager to help **if** you can provide your actual requirements and some sample data that has the exact same structure as your real data. No need to share the real user name, just make something up (as you did). But if you have three columns of data, add example data with 3 columns of data. Furthermore, if I understand your comment correctly you need exactly what Reddy has proposed in his answer, but you indicate it's not sufficient. Can you perhaps add to your question the output you expect (even a handdrawing is fine).

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: Column A is for User, Column B for User Id and Column C for Roles; also assuming that each row shows different role for each user.

Open the VBA editor by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Insert a module, then enter the following code, then run the macro:

```
Sub DeleteUserName()

    Dim lRow As Long
    
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 2 To lRow
        'Set value of User from User Id value
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & x).Value
    
    Next
    'Delete column B - User Id column
    ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Delete

End Sub
```

The value of each cell in column B is copied to column A. Then Column B is deleted.

[image]

Comment: Hi All...thank you so much for taking the time to look at this and apologies for not responding sooner - with Reddy's solution I still have the user ID in column A due to security what I need to see is either the User or User ID replaced with a dummy incrementing value - so the 'real' name of Mr England would become User 1, the 'real' name of Mr Wales would become User 2...and so on...does this make sense now?